# Formatting Output in Flask & Python

Tags: python, list, flask

I've got my web app up and running.

However, I need to post the output of the website using `render_template` To get the output to show in the text output, I have to pass it all at once. I do this using a list, but the list isn't formatted properly in the output.

My web app: http://tomshoe02.pythonanywhere.com/scraper

Sample input: https://dtmwra1jsgyb0.cloudfront.net/groups/5e223506edae743046ecdaa2/matches

An example output (screenshot): https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtSSE.png

An example output: `['{{MatchSchedule|team1=UAlbany eSports|team2=Thomas Esports|team1score=2|team2score=0|winner=1|date=2020-02-07|time=13:00|timezone=PST|dst=yes|vod1=|stream=}}\n', '{{MatchSchedule|team1=King Tornado|team2=|team1score=|team2score=|winner=|date=2020-02-08|time=12:00|timezone=PST|dst=yes|vod1=|stream=}}\n', '{{Ma...`

Desired output:

```
{{MatchSchedule|team1=UAlbany eSports|team2=Thomas Esports|team1score=2|team2score=0|winner=1|date=2020-02-07|time=13:00|timezone=PST|dst=yes|vod1=|stream=}}

{{MatchSchedule|team1=King Tornado|team2=|team1score=|team2score=|winner=|date=2020-02-08|time=12:00|timezone=PST|dst=yes|vod1=|stream=}}
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
import os, sys, subprocess, importlib
from stuff import jloader

directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'tomisgoated'

class BattlefyForm(FlaskForm):
    matchhistory = StringField('Match History Link')

@app.route("/test")
def home():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/lol", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/scraper", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def scraper():
    form = BattlefyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        url = form.matchhistory.data
        result = jloader(url)
        '''
        #result = url
        result = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable,
            "{}/stuff.py".format(directory), url]).decode('iso-8859-1')
        '''
        return render_template("scraper.html", form=form, result=result)
    return render_template("scraper.html", form=form)

@app.route('/base', methods=["GET"])
def base():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.template_filter('nl2br')
def nl2br(s):
    return s.replace("\n", "<br />")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

stuff.py: https://www.codepile.net/pile/Ore8pj5e

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1: Convert list to string before passing to template.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
print("\n".join(list1))
```

### Option 2: Pass the value to the template as-is and fix using Jinja

Additional discussion around this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3971100/12939068

```
<div>
{% for item in list %}
    <div>{{ item }}</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```